# D3 : Re-entrant table function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm still new to Javascript and D3, which I'm using to create the following tabular function below. Correspondingly I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1kwr3myd/25/).

```
function tabulate(head,body) {
  // Select Tag to manipulate
  var table = d3.select("table");
  // Create Head
  var thead = table.selectAll("thead").data([null]);
  thead.enter().append("thead");
  // Populate Head
  var tr = thead.selectAll('tr').data([head]);
  tr.enter().append("tr");
  var th = tr.selectAll('th').data(head);
  th.enter().append("th").text(function(d) { return d; });
  // Create Body
  var tbody = table.selectAll("tbody").data([null]);
  tbody.enter().append("tbody");
  // Populate Body
  var tr = tbody.selectAll('tr').data(body);
  tr.enter().append('tr');
  var td = tr.selectAll('td')
          .data(
            function (body) {
             return head.map(function (item) { return {col: item, row: body[item]}; });
          });
  td.enter().append('td')
    .text(function (d) { return d.row; });
};
```

The function is meant to replace the contents of an existing table with the necessary substructure (thead/tbody/tr tags) and the data provided but I'm getting some weird behavior. For one the contents do not display correctly unless the function has been invoked a few times; it seems substructure must necessarily be constructed during these successive calls before any data is displayed. Secondly it fails to properly swap the tables data in a single call.

Should I be nesting the substructure construction in `.call` chains or should I be doing something else entirely here ?

Given the following data

```
const data = [{"odd":1,"even":2},{"odd":3,"even":4}];
```

I have to call the function three times

```
tabulate(["even"], data); // Adds thead/tbody
tabulate(["even"], data); // Adds tr
tabulate(["even"], data); // Adds th/td elements (Finally)
```

To generate the desired structure

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr><th>even</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I've read through and adapted a number of the D3 examples on [blocks.org](http://bl.ocks.org) and I feel I understand the Join+Create/Update/Delete pattern used by D3. I've also read the commentary under [Issue 91](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/issues/91) on the D3 site discussing the "new" `.merge` method. Mr. Bostock mentions that one might use control flow over a join [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/Rlv0O8xsFhs/jRT8vqAR8OQJ).

Comment: Could you clarify what output you're expecting to get? The `merge` function isn't appropriate unless you're updating the table contents, and I am not sure where that is supposed to happen (if at all) in the code you have written. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah sure, I've been told my questions/answers are too wordy of late so I tried to keep this one short.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note about d3 is that you can use it for "vanilla" (plain) DOM operations; you don't have to bind data every time you want to create or manipulate DOM elements. Instead of trying to create an element by binding `null` to it, you can simply append it to an existing element:

```
function tabulate(head,body) {
  // Select Tag to manipulate
  var table = d3.select("table");

  // Old code:
  // var thead = table.selectAll("thead").data([null]);
  // thead.enter().append("thead");
  // var tr = thead.selectAll('tr').data([head]);
  // tr.enter().append("tr");

  var tr = table.append('thead').append('tr');
```

Unless you want or need an item to have data bound to it, it's better not to try to bind fake data (the array containing `null`) or a big blob of data that isn't used (the `head` array) to an element. In this case, the relevant pieces of the table that should have data bound to them, and that may change if a different dataset is displayed, are the table head cells (`th`) and the contents of the table body, the rows (`tr`s) representing each datum and the table cells (`td`s) containing the values. It would thus be more efficient to write your table code like this:

```
function tabulate(head,body) {
     // Select Tag to manipulate
    var table = d3.select("table")

    // Populate table head
    var th = table.append('thead').append('tr')
      // each th element has an item from the array `head` bound to it
      .selectAll('th').data(head)
      .enter()
        .append('th')
        .text(function(d){ return d; })

    // Populate table body
    var tr = table.append("tbody")
      // each table row has one item from array `body` bound to it
      .selectAll('tr').data(body)
        .enter()
          .append('tr');

    // transform each datum
    var td = tr.selectAll('td').data(function (d) {
            return head.map(function (item) {
              return {col: item, row: d[item]};
            });
         })
        .enter()
          .append('td')
          .text(function (d) { return d.row; });
}
```

See [the updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1kwr3myd/52/)

Comment: The trouble I have with `.append` is that calling `tabulate` a second time does not clear away the elements it made the first time. Say I call `tabulate(['even'], data)` after calling `tabulate(['odd'], data)` then both the **even** and the **odd** data are shown. What I really want is either the **even** or the **odd** data alone. My actual use case populates the table from RPC calls made when the user is clicking other elements, I had hoped that the excessive data binding would resolve this but it makes that actions stagger as originally posted.

Comment: At the moment, your code (and thus my code) doesn't have any way of removing the old data objects—you've added your DOM elements using the `enter()` selection, but you need to remove the `exit()` selection. Have you thought about how to do that?

Comment: btw, if you are looking to do a wholesale replacement of both table head and body, it might be more efficient (and easier) just to delete all the `tr` elements in `thead` and `tbody` and regenerate the contents from the new data. The enter/update/exit paradigm works well if you want to reflect incremental changes to a data set, but it sounds like you would be better off with a simple solution.

Comment: To clean up on exit I understand adding `tbody|thead|tr|th|td.exit().remove()` would do the trick. What I can't work out is how to create the necessary structure in a single call e.g. given `<table></table>` why won't D3 create `tbody|thead` and subsequently `tr` and `tr|th` in the desired structure ? Perhaps wholesale replacement is the way to go.

Comment: For your purposes, it probably is. For a more general case, if there are intervening nodes that need to be created (the `thead`, `thead tr`, and `tbody` elements), there would usually be a function to create that initial table structure, and then an update function that just looks at the elements that change.

Answer (score 0):

After reading a stack of additional posts I found a cryptic snippet that hinted at a solution at the bottom of this [page](http://bl.ocks.org/stepheneb/1183998). I still do not have a complete solution, since I must modify the container element as follows,

```
<table>
 <thead></thead>
 <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

but a partial solution beats no solution and hints at a generalized pattern.
The updated Javascript is as follows :

```
function tabulate(head, body) {
  // Enclosing Tag
  var table = d3.select("table");
  // Head
  var tr = table.select("thead").selectAll("tr").data([head])
  var trDelete = tr.exit().remove();
  var trUpdate = tr.enter().append("tr").merge(tr);
  // tr.each(th);
  var th = trUpdate.selectAll("th").data(function (d,i) {return d;});
  var thDelete = th.exit().remove();
  var thUpdate = th.enter().append("th").merge(th);
  thUpdate.text(function (d) {return d;});
  // Body
  var tr = table.select("tbody").selectAll("tr").data(body);
  var trDelete = tr.exit().remove();
  var trMerged = tr.enter().append("tr").merge(tr);
  var td = trMerged.selectAll("td")
      .data(function (body) {
           return head.map(function (item) { return body[item] });});
  td.enter()  
    .append('td')
    .merge(td)
    .text(function (d) { return d; });
 }
```

The trick it seems is to tie the "create" and "update" subsets of the initial selection, `table.select("thead|tbody").selectAll("TAG")`, together with a `.merge()` (See the `trUpdate` assignments). Then manipulate the combined/merged set in subsequent operations. Doing this generates the `tr` substructure in a single call. Thanks to @i alarmed alien for his/her/its assistance, the "wholesale replacement" quib got me thinking on the right path otherwise I'd be getting thrifty with a sharp utensil or some rope by now. The other information that buttered my toast were the [nested](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) [selections](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/) and [heterogenous nesting](http://seanbowman.me/blog/d3-tables-nesting/) articles.